# How to assign body to defs at later stage in object initialization?

Tags: scala

Since functions are objects in Scala I'd like to initialize class methods by class arguments
for example:

```
class myClass(functionsMap: Map[methodNameString,Function]){
      def method1;
      def method2;
}
```

I want to initialize this methods by this `functionsMap`.

A pseudo-code could be as follows:

```
Map(
  "method1" -> { x => x.size },
  "method2" -> { () => println("hello") }
)
```

Then I'd like to iterate over this map and initialize the methods by this parametarized functions
inside the class as follows:

```
class myClass(functionsMap: Map[methodNameString,Function]) {
      def method1 = functionsMap("method1")
      def method2 = functionsMap("method2")
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how to implement it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible with [Dynamic trait](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.Dynamic):

```
import scala.language.dynamics

class myClass(functionsMap: Map[ String, Function0[Unit]]) extends Dynamic {
  def selectDynamic(methodName: String) = { 
   println("I'm calling " + methodName) 
   functionsMap(methodName).apply()
  } 
}

scala> val funcs = Map("foo" -> (() => {println("I'm method passed outside")}))
// funcs: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,() => Unit] = Map(foo -> <function0>)

scala> new myClass(funcs)
// res12: myClass = myClass@2d298123

scala> res12.foo
I'm calling foo
I'm method passed outside
```

Comment: is there any way of doing it with regular trait?

Comment: wht the differences between them except to the dynamic functions?
performance dif? other restrictions?

Comment: *is there any way of doing it with regular trait?* perhaps it could be written with macroses (I'm simply don't know if they're already support such things), but most likely with much more code. Most significant differences is performance (e.g. no JIT) and IDE support.